# listing file names from the current directory that have png as extension

Tags: python

I am trying to list png image files from current folder I am working on but I get error.please help!

```
import os
def get_imlist(path):
    return [os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith(’.png’)]
```

Comment: My psychic powers tell me that the error is related to the smart quotes (`’`) rather than straight quotes (`'`) in your code.

Comment: If you have posted your error message, @TigerhawkT3 won't have to use his psychic powers...that will save him much efforts...:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `glob` module for this -

Example -

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('*.png')
['this.png']
```

It will return you all files in current directory that end with `.png` extension as a list.

Answer (score 0):

As @TigerhawkT3 spotted, your quotes need to be changed. Here are two possible approaches you can take which should return you the same results:

```
import os, glob

def get_imlist1(path):
    return [os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.png')]

def get_imlist2(path):
    return glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.png'))
```